# ProxyPass setup for multiple tomcat instances

Tags: apache, spring-security, tomcat7, mod-proxy

I tried implementing load balancing using mod_jk with two tomcat instance.

It holds good except for the case of spring security check.
When i try using j_spring securitycheck. it is not working.
Upon googling, this is what was the solution provided.

```
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
ProxyPass /j_spring_security_check ajp://localhost:8009/j_spring_security_check
ProxyPass /j_spring_security_logout ajp://localhost:8009/j_spring_security_logout
```

When i use the above it is working. But the problem is, I  will not be able to refer the second tomcat instance.

httpd.conf :Configurations are

> ```
> LoadModule jk_module modules/mod_jk.so
> JkWorkersFile conf/workers.properties
> JkLogLevel info
> JkLogStampFormat "[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y]"
> JkLogFile logs/mod_jk.log
> JkMount /restservice/* lb
> JkMount /images/* lb
>
> <Location /jkmanager/>
>   JKMount jkstatus
>   Order deny,allow    
>   Allow from all
> </Location>
> ```

Worker File :

```
worker.list=lb
worker.worker1.port=8009
worker.worker1.host=localhost
worker.worker1.type=ajp13


worker.worker2.port=8070
worker.worker2.host=localhost
worker.worker2.type=ajp13



worker.lb.type=lb
worker.lb.balance_workers=worker1,worker2

worker.list=jkstatus
worker.jkstatus.type=status
worker.loadbalancer.sticky_session=TRUE
```

Comment: Use a `<ProxyBalancer>` and define both your Tomcat servers in there, then use the balancer address you set in the `ProxyPass`

Comment: Could you pls elaborate.I am new to these kind of configuration. And i think it is something which is not with mod_jk

Comment: Yes, but neither is `ProxyPass`. It's from `mod_proxy`, not `mod_jk`. Type `ProxyBalancer` into a search engine and you'll find instructions on how to use it.

Comment: I did this one but didnt help me.<Proxy balancer://mycluster>
 BalancerMember ajp://localhost:8009/j_spring_security_check loadfactor=1
 BalancerMember ajp://localhost:8070/j_spring_security_check loadfactor=2
</Proxy>

ProxyPass /j_spring_security_check balancer://mycluster